# How to play the recorded sound in NSLocalNotifiaction

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, localnotification

I implemented local notification in my app but I am just wondering is there a way to play a sound that is not part of the NSMainbundle.Basically in my app, I want user to record a sound that gets played when the local notification is generated instead of playing a pre-recorded sound. I have read out the [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/soundName) but i have also seen 2 -3 Apps on app store which is doing it like the this App [link of the App](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vocal-voice-reminders.-remember/id321959030?mt=8) i am wondering how the are playing custom sounds (sounds which are not the part of NSMainBundel)
Anyone has any idea how I can do it ?

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to utilize the [`AVAudioRecorder`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) and save its recordings to the documents directory of the iPhone.

After the recording is done, you can play the very same files using an [`AVAudioPlayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) via the path of the recorded files.

HTH